# make CGPoint dynamically at bottom for every ios screen devise programmatically

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to programatically place the fb login button at the bottom center of the screen with some margin from the boundary. this is my code is view did load:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  ////background image
  let yourImage = UIImage(named: "main.png")
  let imageview = UIImageView(image: yourImage)
  self.view.addSubview(imageview)

  // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
  if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() == nil){
    print("not logged in")
  } else {
    print("logged in")
  }
  var a = CGPointMake(180, 400)
  var signInButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
  signInButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
  signInButton.center = self.view.convertPoint(a, fromCoordinateSpace: self.view)
  signInButton.delegate = self
  self.view.addSubview(signInButton)
}
```

What is the proper way to dynamically set the position of the button?

[image]

Comment: `self.view.convertPoint(a, fromCoordinateSpace: self.view)` basically gives you the same `a` value.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [layout constraints](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_auto_layout/chapters/UnderstandingAutolayout.html). Otherwise you could use view.frame.maxY and build the rect around that.